# Paypal Sandbox Not Returning to Website

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been successfully testing the SpiceLogic paypal component for Paypal Standard transactions and all has been working fine up until yesterday.  Basically the return from Paypal was working and the IPN notification was fine and sending emails, logging to DB, etc.  What I am finding now (and this is without any further code changes) is that the customer is no longer being redirected and the redirect to website link in Paypal also does not work correctly.  The IPN however is still being fired off and still doing the background processing.
I've tried using the sample code for the component however this also is not working correctly.  At this stage I believe the issue may be something within Paypal Sandbox however I have verified that the Return URL is enabled and there is a valid return adderess.
Does anyone have any ideas as to where I could possibly look for answers.

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing exactly the same problem with my PayPal application (not SpiceLogic, whatever that is). All was working well until about mid-day GMT yesterday, the 4th of March. I have checked this using different browsers on different machines using environments and code that have not changed for ages. It's definitely a Sandbox problem. Let's hope it gets fixed soon.

Update: 2pm GMT Thursday 6th March. Sandbox has now been broken for more than 48 hours. Can anyone else confirm this please. Anyone know how to get this resolved?

Update: 4:30pm GMT Thursday 6th March. It's now working properly again. It was just (over) a 48 hour bug... Thanks Micah.

Answer (score 1):

In the last few days a defect was identified which sounds like the problems you are having.   It impacts some transactions where buyers may not be returned back to your website once a PayPal Payments Standard transaction completes.
You would need to meet the following criteria for your Payments Standard payments:

- "Auto Return" is enabled in your PayPal account
- A value of `return` is specified in the Payments Standard button code
- A value of `2` for the parameter `rm` is specified in the Payments Standard
  button code

To work around this problem, it’s possible to modify an existing Payments Standard integration from sending `rm=2` to `rm=1` which will in turn allow buyers to be redirected back to your `return` URL.
You would find in your post to PayPal the following:

Change this: `<input type=”hidden” name=”rm” value=”2”>`

to this: `<input type=”hidden” name=”rm” value=”1”>`

Please note:
Once the value for `rm` has changed, you will no longer receive specific transaction data via HTTP POST to the URL specified by you in the `return` parameter.
With `rm` set to `1`, some data will be sent via HTTP GET instead.

Update: The correction for this defect has been made as of 3/6/14.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem. I did find out that PayPal has updated their sandbox to require https on the return path to the ipn handler. I also found out from PayPal that when using .NET you need to be using .NET framework 4.5 but found out from Spicelogic that their dll was build with .NET framework 2.0. They are looking into possibly releasing a new version.

See PayPal https://www.paypao-techsupport.com for details on SSL Certificate Upgrade and TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade and IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS

Hopefully Spicelogic will get a new version out quickly. 
THese PayPal changes are currently in the sandbox but not yet in production - the live site. I believe the TLS change occurs in June and the SSL change in September. PayPal has put the updates into the sandbox so developers can get the applications ready for those changes.